# What protocol is used when connecting Protractor directly to browser drivers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In the Protractor Infrasturcture documentation http://www.protractortest.org/#/infrastructure, it says that communication protocol between the test script and the standalone selenium server is http, and between the selenium server and the browser driver is JSON Webdriver Wire Protocol.

But in the documentation on setting up Selenium server https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers, it says there is an option to connect the test script directly to the browser driver.

My question is: When using the direct connect option, what communication protocol is used between the test script and the browser driver?

(reason I'm asking here rather than on Protractor github issues is the contributing guidelines say all questions should be posted on stack overflow or google group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol to communicate with the Selenium server or the drivers is `http` in both cases.
The commands are transmitted using the JSON wire protocol in the message of the http request/response.

Now with Selenium, you can work directly with the driver of the targeted browser or you can connect to the Selenium server which will transmit the commands to the driver.